# What does id<Litigating> mean?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know "id" type, but what does  `id<Litigating>` mean ?

```
@protocol Litigating
-(int) sue:( id<Litigating> ) someone;
@end
```

Comment: I wonder why someone -1'd the question.

Comment: Maybe because the word Litigating is scary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of Objective-C protocols as Java, C#, etc. Interfaces on speed.

This is a variable of any class, conforming to the protocol `Litigation` *(this is as far as traditional OOP goes without jumping hoops)*:

```
id<Litigation> someone;
```

This is a variable of the class `Company` *(and subclasses)*, that also conforms to `Litigation`:

```
Company<Litigation>* someone;
```

This is a variable of class `Company`, that also conforms to both `Litigation` **and** NSCopying**:

```
Company<Litigation, NSCopying>* someone;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
id<SomeProtocol>
```

implies that this object implements `SomeProtocol`. It must be implementing all the required methods belonging to `SomeProtocol`.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the parameter is not only of type `id` but also conforms to the `Litigating` (formal) protocol, cf. [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-TPXREF148).